# My AWS ElasticBeanstalk application does not show up in the Web Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I initialized a EB application and created an environment and it worked but my application does not show up in the Web Console.

Comment: Have you deployed it using `eb deploy` to the aws infra already?

Comment: I didn't. I deleted the directory, I initialized. I'm trying to delete the project/application from AWS.

Comment: Are you sure you have selected the correct region in the console?

Comment: @RohitBanga I am pretty sure. I set it for eu-west-1 (Ireland) and choose the correct region in AWS Web Console.